# My first hello word program in MistQL is throwing exception Expected RuntimeValueType.Number, got RuntimeValueType.String

Tags: python

I was trying this tutorial given in the MistQL for a personal work but this below code is throwing exception as  given below

```
import mistql

data="{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"
query = '@.foo'
results = mistql.query(query, data)
print(results)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Temp\sample.py", line 4,
> in 
> purchaserEmails = mistql.query(query, data)   File "C:\Python3.10.0\lib\site-packages\mistql\query.py", line 18, in query
> result = execute_outer(ast, data)   File "C:\Python3.10.0\lib\site-packages\mistql\execute.py", line 73, in
> execute_outer
> return execute(ast, build_initial_stack(data, builtins))   File "C:\Python3.10.0\lib\site-packages\typeguard_*init*_.py", line 1033,
> in wrapper
> retval = func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python3.10.0\lib\site-packages\mistql\execute.py", line 60, in
> execute
> return execute_fncall(ast.fn, ast.args, stack)   File "C:\Python3.10.0\lib\site-packages\typeguard_*init*_.py", line 1033,
> in wrapper
> retval = func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python3.10.0\lib\site-packages\mistql\execute.py", line 28, in
> execute_fncall
> return function_definition(arguments, stack, execute)   File "C:\Python3.10.0\lib\site-packages\mistql\builtins.py", line 37, in
> wrapped
> return fn(arguments, stack, exec)   File "C:\Python3.10.0\lib\site-packages\mistql\builtins.py", line 168, in
> dot
> return _index_single(RuntimeValue.of(right.name), left)   File "C:\Python3.10.0\lib\site-packages\mistql\builtins.py", line 295, in
> _index_single
> assert_type(index, RVT.Number)   File "C:\Python3.10.0\lib\site-packages\mistql\runtime_value.py", line 344,
> in assert_type
> raise MistQLTypeError(f"Expected {expected_type}, got {value.type}") mistql.exceptions.MistQLTypeError: Expected
> RuntimeValueType.Number, got RuntimeValueType.String

Comment: The error you pasted does not match with the code in your example. There is no variable called `purchasersEmail` on line 4 in your sample code so you're obviously not running the file you pasted (Hint: the one that is effectively executed is `C:\Temp\sample.py`). Please provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](/help/mcve). Meanwhile the error is easy to understand: you are providing a string (e.g. `"abc"` or `"123"`) where your code expects a number (e.g. `123`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!.that’s my bad I altered the name (purchasers Email)of the result variable (results)  on the code before posting it here. The error truly is simple but it is hard to identify the Params which were causing it.

Comment: So what actually prevents you from [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72584594/edit) your question to fix it so that the code and the result match?

Comment: You are passing a string representation of your json data (`"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"`) where your lib is waiting for an actual dict (`{"foo": "bar"}`, i.e. the result from decoding the previous string representation). Have a look at the `mistql` lib source code to understand why this ends up with the above (quite misleading IMO) error. So either decode your json string (i.e. `data=json.loads("{\"foo\": \"bar\"}")` - note this will require `import json`), or pass the correct data directly (i.e. `data={"foo": "bar"}`)

Answer (score 0):

Strings passed as data into MistQL's query method correspond to MistQL string types, and thus the `@.foo` query is attempting to index the string `"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}")` using the `"foo"` value, leading to the error above.

MistQL is expecting native dictionaries and lists. The correspondence between Python data types and MistQL data types can be seen [here](https://www.mistql.com/docs/reference/implementations/py#type-correspondence-between-python-and-mistql)

That being said, the error message is indeed very confusing and should be fixed post-haste! Issue [here](https://github.com/evinism/mistql/issues/166)